# Свечения граней объекта

Tags: unity3d, освещение

Моя задача - сделать свечения граней кубика как здесь:

[image]

У меня нет идей как это сделать. Какие варианты вы можете посоветовать?

Comment: посмотрите например это https://github.com/jjxtra/UnityLightsaber

Comment: еще можно попробовать копнуть в сторону bloom эффекта

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Bloom - вещь хорошая. Но у меня кубик то не светится... Emission я добавил в материал. Но Он НЕ дает того, свечения, что мне нужно (если коротко. То вооообще не светится кубик как лампочка). Мне нужно как то это свечение ласпочки добавить. Световые мечи - отличная идея для рассмотрения.. Но может есть более простой вариант, чем разбираться в тонне чужого кода?

Comment: посмотрите ассет, там этот эффект достигается шейдером от системы частиц

Comment: а мне кажется блум это то что нужно, только применить его надо хитро, не к основной сцене, а к слою и потом уже наложить поверх сцены